# How to declare additional attributes when subclassing str?

Tags: python, subclass, mypy

Consider the following class:

```
class StrWithInt(str):
    def __new__(cls, content, value: int):
        ret = super().__new__(cls, content)
        ret.value = value
        return ret
```

This class just works fine, but when using `mypy`, the following error occurs:
`"StrWithInt" has no attribute "value"  [attr-defined]`

Is there some way to explicitly state the attribute in this case? What is the proper way to solve this issue?

Note that this is a minimal example and not using a subclass of `str` is not an option in the non-minimal example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```py
class StrWithInt(str):
    value: int

    def __new__(cls, content, value: int):
        ret = super().__new__(cls, content)
        ret.value = value
        return ret
```